# Why does a parbox of height zero consume vertical space?

Tags: spacing, boxes, vertical, parbox

Assume we have a document where we have one paragraph of text, followed by two vspace boxes, followed by another paragraph of text. I thought that I could insert a parbox with zero height between the vspace boxes without increasing the space between the paragraphs. After all, it would have a height of zero. However, my assumption was not correct and thus my question is where the additional space comes from.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\vspace{1cm}

\parbox[c][0pt]{\linewidth}{} % When we add this line, the space between both paragraphs increases

\vspace{1cm}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Below you can see screenshots of the compiled documents (first row) and in the second row I drew how that boxes I think should look like. The first column depicts the situation when we replace the parbox with a simple string. Of course, that text consumes some space. The second column depicts the situation I expected when inserting the parbox. Technically, we get a new line between the vspace boxes, but since this line has height and depth zero above and below the baseline, the line "collapes" and the space does not increase. The third column finally depicts the situation as it is. It seems that the zero-height parbox introduces additional space of exactly one `baselineskip`. Why is that the case and where exactly is the baseline placed within that box with a height of `baselineskip`? I thought that the distance between the baseline of the new line and bottom edge of the upper vspace box is determined by the element with the highest height in that line (just like the "L" in column 1 of the picture).

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: I don't know, but since `\par` ends the line and the paragraph, I would expect a `\baselineskip` + `\parskip` (default in the standard classes=`0pt plus1pt`) for the next paragraph to start. Unrelated2: width can also be 0: try `\fbox{\parbox[c][0pt]{0pt}{x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x }}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's minimize the example

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\showoutput

\begin{document}

Test

\vspace{30pt}% so we can see it better in the output

\parbox[c][0pt]{\linewidth}{}

\vspace{30pt}

Test

\end{document}
```

In the console output we see

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 455.9513fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 3.16669
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 311.33333fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 T
....\kern-0.83334
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 30.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 9.5
...\hbox(2.5+0.0)x345.0, glue set 330.0fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\mathon
....\vbox(2.5+-2.5)x0.0
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 30.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 311.33333fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 T
....\kern-0.83334
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 30.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
```

The `\parbox` corresponds to

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0                  % <- indent
....\mathon                              % <- start math mode
....\vbox(2.5+-2.5)x0.0                  % <- a \vbox from \vcenter
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil  % <- the glue for vertical centering
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil  % <- the glue for vertical centering
....\mathoff
```

because the `[c]` option uses internally math mode to do `\vcenter` and the actual height and depth are 2.5pt (because of the standard height of the formula axis). However, the explanation lies just before this part, namely

```
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil     % <- the paragraph for Test has ended
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0                   % <- no \rightskip
...\glue 30.0                               % <- the \vspace{30pt}
...\glue 0.0                                % <- from \vspace implementation
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0             % <- a paragraph has started
...\glue(\baselineskip) 9.5                 % <- vertical glue
...\hbox(2.5+0.0)x345.0, glue set 330.0fil  % <- a line
```

The final `\hbox` is what encloses the `\parbox` and is preceded by glue from `\baselineskip` in the amount of 9.5pt: indeed, the height of the box is 2.5pt and 9.5 + 2.5 = 12 (the value of `\baselineskip`).

Similarly, you see after the box

```
....\penalty 10000                                  % <- from \par
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil             % <- a paragraph has ended
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0                           % <- no \rightskip
...\glue 30.0                                       % <- \vspace{30pt}
...\glue 0.0                                        % <- from \vspace
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0                     % <- a paragraph has started
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669                     % <- glue
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 311.33333fil  % <- the paragraph for Test
```

The `\penalty 10000` is due to the blank line after `\parbox`, which ends the paragraph.

If you do `\parbox[c][0pt]{\linewidth}{X}`, then you'd see more: an `Overfull \hbox` message, due to the indentation being followed by a box that make more the line width. However the vertical spacing between the two instances of “Test” would not change, because the parbox fits vertically in the `\baselineskip`.

In other words, you have three paragraphs, with added vertical space between them.
Actually, the `\vspace` commands are a kind of red herring. If you consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Test 1

Test 2

\parbox[c][0pt]{\linewidth}{}

Test 3

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

It would be different if you used `\nointerlineskip\vbox to 0pt{}`: here's a side by side comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\dimen0}{Test 1}

\parbox{\dimen0}{Test 1

Test 2

Test 3}%
\parbox{\dimen0}{Test 1

Test 2

\nointerlineskip\vbox to 0pt{}

Test 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this very insightful answer. I'm trying to fully understand it. First, I struggle with `\vbox(2.5+-2.5)x0.0`. You say that it has height and depth 2.5pt. I'm not familiar with this kind of output, but it looks like it has a *positive* height and *negative* depth of 2.5pt. I’m wondering why it has height and depth at all since the parbox is completely empty, and how I should interpret a negative depth? And second, why does the enclosing box have a different height/depth specification (`\hbox(2.5+0.0)` vs `\vbox(2.5+-2.5)`)?

Comment: And another follow-up question: When I position the parbox with `t` instead of `c`, I get the following output: `...\glue(\baselineskip) 10.05556` followed by `...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 330.0fil` Where does the value `10.05556` come from? I would have thought that when the hbox is of height and depth zero, then TeX should take the full 12pt glue from \baselineskip.

Comment: @user1494080 The strange notation is due to the fact that the box comes from `\vcenter`, so it is raised in such a way that the reference point is midway from top to bottom and 2.5pt (the formula axis height) above the baseline. The depth is recorded as negative because the real box height is 0pt, but it's not taken into account for interline glue computations. Sorry, but with `\parbox[t][0pt]{\linewidth}{}` I get `\glue(\baselineskip) 12.0`

Comment: Sorry, I did not only replace `c` by `t`, but also the first `Test` by `Testj`. Then, the hbox of the first paragraph gets depth `1.94444`, and so the `\baselineskip` consumes only `10.05556`.

Comment: Out of curiosity (although it's not directly related to this problem): Why does `\rightskip` always occur in the output although we do not use it, but `\leftskip` does not?

Comment: @user1494080 That explains the different glue, indeed. Apparently `\rightskip` glue is *always* added.

Comment: How can I retrieve the axis height from LaTeX? I would like to enter commands such as `\the\axisheight` or `\vspace{\axisheight}`. I guess it's not always 2.5pt. For example, imagine that I want to vertically center the content of a parbox on some "virtual line". I have arranged the line containing the parbox such that its baseline coincides with the virtual line. Now `\parbox[c][0pt]...` would typeset the box content slightly too high (by the amount of axis height). My solution would be `\vspace{\axisheight}\parbox[c][0pt]...`, which would position the axis exactly on the virtual line.

Comment: @user1494080 `\makeatletter\check@mathfonts\setlength{\axisheight}{\fontdimen22\textfont2}\makeatother` Note that the formula axis height changes with the font size. For just the standard one for normal size, issue the `\setlength` instruction at begin document: `\newlength{\axisheight}\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\check@mathfonts\setlength{\axisheight}{\fontdimen22\textfont2}}\makeatother`

Answer (score 3):

First it is worth noting that `\vspace` makes glue not a box, the other half of TeX's box and glue model for text layout.

If I modify your example to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\vspace{1cm}

%\parbox[c][0pt]{\linewidth}{} % When we add this line, the space between both paragraphs increases
X
%.

\vspace{1cm}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Then it is easier to see what is going on. you have three paragraphs of text two with lipsum, and one with X. The height of a text line does not (normally) depend on the specific characters in the line, if you replace `X` by `.` the character is smaller but the middle paragraph takes the same space. The `\parbox` acts like a zero sized white character so is placed in a one-line paragraph and takes up the same vertical space as any other one line paragraph.

It may be worth noting that the parbox is not `\linwidth` wide it is of zero width. If you placed any content inside the `\parbox` such as

```
\parbox[c][0pt]{\linewidth}{.} %
```

then you will get an overfull hbox warning as you have a box of width `\linewidth` indented by `\parindent` (17pt).

Comment: " The height of a text line does not (normally) depend on the specific characters in the line": I'd like to kow, how is this space determined, and is it possible to create a line with really zero height/depth? I'd like to use it to insert some `\tikzmark` without adding annoying spaces.

Comment: @tobiasBora it's `\baselineskip` but better to post a new question rather than ask as comments on an old answer. but If I remember correctly `\tikzmark` is not like `\parbox` it does not start a paragraph so the issues are different.

Comment: I already asked one here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623544 I found some dirty tricks to try to reduce it, but I'm not convinced by the result as it's always quite hacky and not very resilient (sometimes I've space and I can't explain why)